# Inconsistent Hive Left Join Results

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

I composed a simple left out join hiveql
`select * from a left outer join b on (a.f1=b.f1 and a.f2=b.f2)`
The total count of above query result is `798,608`.
However, the total number of records in table a is `780,499`, which doesn't match.

I tried to find all records that only exist in the left join results but not in table a; the results returned blank.

I even tried to create 2 small tables (a' and b') with a few records and the count of the left join result matches the count of table a' records, as expected.

What could cause the inconsistent results?

Comment: my guess is you have 1 to many relationship.  Your table b most likely has multiple records for a few of the records in table a.

Comment: I would try a group by on table b for the fields f1 and f2 and run a count on that then count table b without a group by and see if the results are the same.

Comment: @DavidLee, you are correct! Thanks for the quick turnaround!

Comment: You are welcome, good luck on your future coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David Lee. There are 1 to many situation in table b.
Problem solved.